# Disable expired password change dialog in PAM

Tags: linux, passwords, pam

I try to find a way to switch off the password change dialog
you get when you login with a expired password.

"""
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user xyz.
Current Password:
"""

Instead the user shouldn't simply rejected. I set in
the sssd.conf `chpass_provider = none`
and I tried billions of pam configs without success I always get
the dialog. here my password auth

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        optional      pam_afs_session.so
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_access.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
session     required      pam_afs_session.so
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  We'd also like to disable this message, and have thus far gone down the same route as you with `chpass_provider=none`, but to no avail. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

@sterni1971 - I just found a way to fix this, and deny the user instead of allowing them to change the password.  This revolves around using Kerberos, so if you are not using Kerberos (which, by looking at your original post, you may not be), then apologies.. but hopefully it helps someone else in that case.

Check out the `fail_pwchange` option for `pam_krb5` (see: [pam-krb5 documentation](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/pam-krb5/pam-krb5.html)) It can be set in the /etc/krb5.conf, but I found it worked when setting it on my pam_krb5 line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
auth       sufficient   pam_krb5.so forwardable renew_lifetime=30d ticket_lifetime=1d1h force_first_pass fail_pwchange
```